# How to use custom Controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a custom control in C# ( Overridden methods in Button control and added new events) . I need to use this control in my `wpf` application. In `WinForms` i can use this by `ToolBox(right click) --> Choose Items -->Browse`. where as in WPF i can not import the custom controls. Is there any way to do this

Comment: You should clarify whether your control is one you created for WinForms or is a new one created specifically in WPF.

Comment: The control is created in `WindowsFormsControlLibrary`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

might need a rebuild for the certain project then a xaml file should be active. Your custom control should appear in the toolbox. if it doesn't show. you can do the following:

in your xaml file, somewhere in the header tag, where you see many of the xmlns:yyy, add a new xmlns: for example:

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyProject">
```

where custom is any identifier for the name space and MyProject is the namespace. Dont worry about this because when you type "xmlns:custom=" (without the quotes) intellisense will give you choice of existing namespaces currently referenced. so just choose the appropriate namespace from the drop down and press enter.

now scroll down to where you want to put your custom control and:

```
<custom:MyControl Content="Click Me!" Click="Button_Click" />
```

custom:MyControl is from the xmlns:**custom** (above) and the Control name, **MyControl**
**Content** is the Content property assigned "Click Me!" and **Click** is the Click event with the handler "Button_Click".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are talking about a WinForms user control here, not a WPF one? If so, I'd suggest you read the following article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875.aspx

I might add that it may be a good idea to simply create a WPF user control - the process has improved much compared to WinForms, also the content model should make things quite a bit easier.