# WPF: Anyone else using textboxes instead of labels?

Tags: wpf, textbox, label

I'm just curious..
In my application I'm using "readonly and borderless" textboxes instead of using labels. The textboxes are based on this Style I keep in my resource file:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="LabelLeftStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Basic}">
        <Setter Property="Background"      Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"      Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly"      Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height"          Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width"           Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth"        Value="155"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"       Value="False"/>
    </Style>
```

Just curious..is anyone else doing the same ? I found the WPF Label difficult to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `TextBlock`s instead of `Label`s](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjoshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com%2F2007%2F07%2F04%2Fdifferences-between-label-and-textblock%2F&ei=IvpbTfKMOIihOuCfidcL&usg=AFQjCNHiBWhg8nfwPOxZRa7Cft0RGQxWZQ&sig2=1wa_NBq4qhObtcsye3SgmQ).

- `TextBox` = editable text field
- `Label` = uneditable text usually tied to a form field
- `TextBlock` = generic uneditable text

Comment: One more point: TextBox = uneditable text, but selectable (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2506504/13441)

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you this much, we use `TextBlock` and `Label` extensively for static text display in multiple WPF applications without issue. How was the `Label` difficult to use? Perhaps if you list some specific problems we could provide some guidance.

Comment: How about needing to take care when binding to strings, because '_' is interpreted specially.

Answer (score 1):

This is really strange that you have chosen to use text boxes (styled in special way) over labels. Because text boxes are designed for a different purpose... Usually the choice is whether to use `TextBlock` or `Label`.

You haven't mentioned why exactly labels are hard to use... If it is because of extra margins that label has by default, then it is easy to fix with a style for all labels in you application.

Anyway, there is a good article about the difference between `TextBlock` and `Label` that describes what are the reasons why such a control as `Label` exist: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/