# Extend Listbox or use alternative?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am creating some kind of chat style application.
The Listbox is getting filled by its ItemSource which ist a Binding to a List. "Message" is a custom class containing various properties. The ListBox contains a DataTemplate which is used to display the Message-Item properly.

I've got a few problems when I am using a ListBox:
1. The user can not select text.
2. The ListBox does not automatically scroll down when an item is getting added to the List.

I'd like to use something like a TextBox, but I just couldn't figure out how to use some kind of DataTemplate and bind the Text-Property to a List. Of course, the text should be formattable.

Is there anything I can do to solve my problem? I thought about extending the ListBox-Control to a Auto-Scrolling one, but this wouldn't solve my problem concerning text selection.

Comment: Why not use an `ItemsControl` and implement your own stuff to auto-scroll it? I doubt you'll need to track `SelectedItem`, and without it you can select your Text (Providing you use `Labels` and not `TextBlocks`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
I copied the ItemTemplate and pasted it into a new `ItemsControl`-Control. After that I wrapped a `ScrollViewer` around the `ItemsControl`. I added an eventhandler to the `ListChanged` event. Inside the eventhandler I called the ScrollToBottom-Method of the ItemsControl-Wrapping ScrollViewer which Matěj Zábský posted.
To solve the problem concerning text selection, I used a TextBox with specific properties changed.
[Any way to make a WPF textblock selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136435/any-way-to-make-a-wpf-textblock-selectable)

Thank you, Rachel and Matěj.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use DataTemplate and make each item in the ListBox a TextBox.

As for the "2. The ListBox does not automatically scroll down when an item is getting added to the List.", call [ScrollToBottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltobottom.aspx) on the ListBox's ScrollViewer (you can use [LogicalTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.aspx) to find it).

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to re-think and to use some kind of ReachTextBox plus TextBox for typing.