# How can I make TextBlock as selectable so that user can copy its text

Tags: wpf, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Any way to make a WPF textblock selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136435/any-way-to-make-a-wpf-textblock-selectable)

Can I make a textblock selectable in WPF application so that a user can copy it.

Comment: Ah damn, Jay Riggs is right... I should have considered before re-iterating. +1

Comment: The question can't be answered by erroneous answer with over 20 up-vote  from provided link. I voted this question to reopen. It is no sense that it more one year old.

Comment: I found a better solution. Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627524/332528

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just make it into a TextBox that's Read Only which just looks like a TextBlock, kind of like;

```
<Style x:Key="ReadOnlyTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
   <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
   <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
               <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                             Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                             IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}"
                             Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

The ScrollViewer ContentElement would be in a TextBox by default, you could substitute for a ContentPresenter instead if you like also.

Then put it into effect;

```
<TextBox Text="Blah Blah Blah you can copy me!" Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBox}"/>
```

Hope this helps!

**ADDENDUM:** As @doodleus pointed out in the comments. Template binding the Content Property within the template may be necessary. As "ContentElement" is a *named part* of the Silverlight TextBox control. One of the little nuance differences to watch for in the different xaml Variants. I must not have paid attention to the Tags when I originally created the example. So kudos to him for correcting me.

Comment: you can also Tab throw it in this case  :)

Comment: one key bit that is missing is the following attribute in the scrollviewer:  Content="{TemplateBinding Text}" . without this, the text in the textbox will not be visible.

Comment: or better yet, just do this:

<TextBox x:Name="textBlockProductId"
     Background="Transparent"
     BorderThickness="0"
     Text="{Binding SelectedProductId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

Comment: @doodlleus test it as is.

Comment: I did, it needs the addition I gave

Comment: @doodlleus I apologize, you're absolutely correct. "ContentElement" is a named part specific to the Silverlight variation of the control making direct template binding not required. I must have skimmed right past the tags when I originally created the example years ago. Thanks and I've updated the answer accordingly to reflect your insight. Cheers