# Text selection on textblock and label wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a form, which includes TextBlocks, Lables, Borders. And I want to be able to select text with the mouse like it would be some text in the table in MS Word or HTML table. And I can't use TextBox or RichTextBox instead. Is there a way to achive my goal?

```
<Grid Margin="20">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="some text in TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="another text in Label"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
<Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="one more  in TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="one more text in Label"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't use a styled TextBoxes instead? eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136435/any-way-to-make-a-wpf-textblock-selectable or http://geekswithblogs.net/mhildreth/archive/2008/06/25/selectable-labels-in-wpf-to-allow-copy-and-paste.aspx

Comment: You can use a `TextBox` with `IsReadOnly ="True"` instead of `TextBlock` for this purpose

Comment: Was just about to ask the exact [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720096/how-can-i-make-textblock-as-selectable-so-that-user-can-copy-its-text/12720189#12720189) thing

Comment: Use a readonly textbox instead and render it like a label like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2506504/4746087)

Comment: Please clarify... do you want to select text across the textblock AND the label or within one control?

Comment: @grek40, Well, may be I can use TextBoxes...But it allows me to select text across ONE control, but I need to select all the text or part it. Like it would be on a web page. On a web page I can select whatever I want however I want.

Answer (score 3):

Use TextBox instead of a TextBlock, like the following code:

```
<TextBox
     Background="Transparent"
     TextWrapping="Wrap"
     Text="{Binding Desired, Mode=OneWay}"
     IsReadOnly="True"
     BorderThickness="0"/>
```

To make it cleaner, careate a template for the TextBlock and use the previous TextBox inside it.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="test2"
           FontSize="16"
           IsTextSelectionEnabled="true"
           SelectionHighlightColor="Green"
           x:Name="test"      
           Foreground="Black"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           TextAlignment="Left"/>
```

Just set `IsTextSelectionEnabled` to true.
You can also chagne color of selected text by changing `SelectionHighlightColor` property.

Comment: You can't use it in Win7, as written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35091222/4165377) (I can confirm this).

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, can't see these properties for a TextBlock

Comment: Can't see these properties, also running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10