# Can't edit Textblock content in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock

I'm working on my first WPF application and I notice that I'm not able to edit the text values in any of my textblocks.

I can't seem to find anything wrong here that would prevent me from changing it...

```
<Label Content="Line Terminator" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"></Label>
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtLineTerm" Focusable="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Padding="3"></TextBlock>
</Border>
<Label Content="Field Terminator" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5"></Label>
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtFieldTerm" Focusable="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Padding="3"></TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Can anyone see the problem? I feel like there's a concept that I'm missing here. Any explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136435/any-way-to-make-a-wpf-textblock-selectable

Comment: Are you asking how to edit the `TextBlock` at runtime, or designtime?  Despite the accepted answer, both are possible... *(What a `TextBlock` **cannot** do is have a user click on it and edit it in-place, like a `TextBox`)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TextBlock is not editable. Use TextBox instead.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [EditableTextBlock](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72544/Editable-Text-Block-in-WPF) as shown in the link