# How to enable copying of data but not cutting and pasting in a text block

Tags: .net, wpf

I have created a custom control using WPF in .NET framework. Its basically a text block which displays whatever text I type in a text box below it. What I want to do is that a user should be able to copy that text but not cut or paste it. 
Can anyone give me an idea how to do this?

Comment: do a button "copy" next to it - which copys the text to the user clipboard or disable the textbox so the user can copy it only

Comment: [make it read-only?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to make a WPF textblock selectable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136435/any-way-to-make-a-wpf-textblock-selectable)